# When is template-driven form control being initialized?

Tags: angular, forms

I can't find any information about template-driven form control initialization. I noticed that on any lifecycle hook, even `AfterViewInit`, the controls are still undefined.

To test it, I prepared some minimal example:

template

```html
<form ngForm #testForm="ngForm">
  <input name="test1" [(ngModel)]="test1Value"/>
</form>
```

component

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('testForm')
  testForm: NgForm;

  test1Value: string = '';

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.testForm.controls);
    }
}
```

on Chrome debugger, I check the `testForm` inside `ngAfterViewInit` - the form is initialized, but the `controls` is an empty object.
However, without using debugger, the object written to console appears to have all the controls in place - which suggests it is being initialized later, between the `console.log` call and `console.log` execution.

Comment: `#testForm` and `this.testForm` are different variables. 1st is visible only inside template. 2nd just a property of your class and noone will initialize it for you.

Comment: @Dimanoid it seems like you haven't noticed `@ViewChild`

Comment: Oh, yes, my fail. :)

Comment: I did some tests and it looks strange. The only way I found to be sure the controls are initialized is to subscribe to `form.valueChanes`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testform

Comment: I faced the same issue and ran into the same fix using setTimeout(() => ...), you can avoid to set timeout 'ms' though but I'm looking for a better solution